# Casting error on android device and not on simulator

Tags: codenameone

I see the following error from android tablet from log. Is there any issue in converting component to container in android?

Comment: Your code assumes that the type of all the children of the Container `c` is `Container`, but your cast exception demonstrates that this assumption is wrong. However, your native log doesn't help to understand what you are wrongly casting because the class names are obfuscated. Maybe you can do a new build with ProGuard disabled to have a more significant log. Moreover, there are Layouts (like TextModeLayout) and Components (like InputComponents) that are rendered differently on Android and on iPhone: you can do a test with an Android skin and an iPhone skin to see if there are differences.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments, I don't know why you have this casting error: because the class names in your log are obfuscated (by Proguard, that is used by default for Android), try to disable it temporarily to have a more readable log (I'm referring to the build hint `android.enableProguard=false`).

I have a lot of casting in my Codename One code. In general, for such cases, I use a code like the following:

```
        Container myCnt = new Container();
        myCnt.add(new Label("Test"));
        myCnt.add(new Container());

        for (Component cmp : myCnt.getChildrenAsList(true)) {
            if (cmp instanceof Container) {
                Container myChildCnt = (Container) cmp;
                // do what I need with myChildCnt
            } else {
                Log.p("cmp is not a Container, it is: " + cmp, Log.WARNING);
            }
        }
```

The only notable difference with your code is the log to investigate the casting error. In this case, the log is:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,76 - cmp is not a Container, it is: Label[x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 name=null, text = Test, gap = 2]
```

Remember to try Android and iPhone skins in the Simulator to see if there are differences.

Comment: After adding build hint android.enableProguard=false, I don't see any detailed error message. Message is same as before. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a label there and the answer seems to be correct. If it's an infinite progress container it might be a label for that. It might be something else but that's hard to guess.